# test_os failed при сборке Python3.10.5 из исходников

Tags: python, python-3.10

Собирал Python3.10.5 из исходников:

- Установил зависимости, как узазано на официальном сайте:

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get install build-essential gdb lcov pkg-config \
       libbz2-dev libffi-dev libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev \
       libncurses5-dev libreadline6-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev \
       lzma lzma-dev tk-dev uuid-dev zlib1g-dev
  ```
- Создал директорию для установки:

  ```
  $ mkdir ~/.python/python3.10.5
  ```
- Скачал архив с официального сайта:

  ```
  $ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.5/Python-3.10.5.tgz
  ```
- Распаковал и вошёл в распакованную директорию:

  ```
  $ tar -xzf Python-3.10.5.tgz
  $ cd Python-3.10.5/
  ```
- Запустил конфигурацию и компиляцию:

  ```
  $ ./configure --enable-optimizations --prefix=~/.python/python3.10.5/
  $ make -j6
  ```
- Запустил тесты:

  ```
  $ make test
  ```

В результате не проходят тесты test_os:

```
Ran 11 tests in 0.008s                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                       
FAILED (failures=7, errors=3, skipped=1)                                                                                                               
test test_os failed                                                                                                                                    
1 test failed again:                                                                                                                                   
    test_os                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                       
== Tests result: FAILURE then FAILURE ==                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                       
412 tests OK.                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                       
1 test failed:                                                                                                                                         
    test_os                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                       
14 tests skipped:                                                                                                                                      
    test_devpoll test_gdb test_ioctl test_kqueue test_msilib                                                                                           
    test_ossaudiodev test_startfile test_tix test_tk test_ttk_guionly
    test_winconsoleio test_winreg test_winsound test_zipfile64

1 re-run test:
    test_os

Total duration: 5 min 54 sec
Tests result: FAILURE then FAILURE
make: *** [Makefile:1224: test] Ошибка 2
```